# Adding play, pause, stop and progress bar to youtube player in windows phone

Tags: video, windows-phone-8, youtube

I have been able to write a very simple youtube player that can play a simple video from youtube. But right now I am trying to add some video play utilities when the video is playing.

Like the play, pause, stop rewind, forward button, video progress bar with the progress time.

To give a better user experience. But I dont have an idea. I have search but not really getting a head on.

I would paste my code snippet below for assistance.

The code below is the part that plays and call youtube player.

```
 this.SetProgressIndicator(true,"Loading video ......");
        var videoUri = await MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("8pcGyWt_2As", MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTubeQuality.Quality480P, MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTubeQuality.Quality480P);
        if (videoUri != null)
        {
            this.SetProgressIndicator(false,null);
            player.Source = videoUri.Uri;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I was able to solve the problem by using this object in windows phone 8

MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();

This object solves the problem for playing videos with all the controls you need in your media player